# Scanf() does not distinguish between brackets

Tags: c, scanf

I have this test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    int a, b;

    int ret = scanf("( %d , %d )", &a, &b);


    if (ret != 2 ){

        printf("Wrong input!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Everything fine\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, the main function expects input for example `(10, 15)`. This input `(10, 15test` fails. But this input `(10, 15]` is OK. Why? How can I distiguish between types of brackets using scanf()?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI g++

Comment: `scanf()` is not the proper tool for the job.

Comment: Why do you compile C code with a C++ compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note there's no need for a space before %d -- all numeric scanf specifiers, and also %s but not %c and %[...], skip any leading whitespace the same as space. Spaces are needed before the comma and the %1[)] if you want to allow whitespace there, which your example data doesn't show.

```
int a,b; char c[2 /* or more */];

int ret = scanf("(%d ,%d %1[)]", &a,&b,c);
if( ret == 3 ) // all good
```

Answer (score 2):

Both these can be used and `scanf` will successfully extract two `int`s:

```
(10, 15test
(10, 15]
```

The part not matching, `test` and `]`, will be left in the input stream so the next `scanf` done will most likely fail if `test` or `]` is not expected.

That means that if you have a loop:

```c
while (scanf("( %d , %d )", &a, &b) == 2) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}
```

and give it the input above, only the first `scanf` will succeed.

To discard everything after the succeessful extraction, you can read until end of line or just read complete lines all the time and then use `sscanf` to parse one line at a time:

```c
char buf[1024];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && sscanf(buf, "( %d , %d )", &a, &b) == 2) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}
```

If you want to verify that a `)` comes after the numbers, you need to extract `)`:

```
char buf[2];
scanf(" ( %d , %d %1[)]", &a, &b, buf) == 3
```

(or using `sscanf` as above)